# Determine which web server is being used from within code

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

Is it possible, pragmatically, to tell whether an ASP.NET web app is running in the Cassini web server in Visual Studio, or in IIS?

**Background and reason for asking:**

In quite a few of our apps, we bypass the normal login settings in a login page by checking the machine name, or by checking to see if the Client IP is localhost.  (127.0.0.1 or :::1) so that we can test and have the app behave differently while debugging on our development PCs.

The Machine name approach is OK, but the wee need to change the code when we get a new Dev PC.  I realize this isn't too often, but it feels sloppy.  Also, with several developers working on it, we have to list all of our machines in the "if" statement.

As for the "localhost" approach, I don't like it.  It seems to add another attack surface. I worry about someone getting onto one of the web servers and running it locally and seeing stuff.

So I wonder if there's a way from code to detect that the website is running from Visual Studio with the Cassini web server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I identify whether an ASP.NET site is being run "normally" or in "debug" via Visual Studio?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713626/how-can-i-identify-whether-an-asp-net-site-is-being-run-normally-or-in-debug)

Comment: That's different - it's asking how to tell if it's being run in debug mode. I could just as easily be in Visual Studio in release mode.

Comment: Ah ok sorry. I guess you don't want to use [HttpRequest.IsLocal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.islocal.aspx) either?

Comment: Thanks, but not for this question.  It's cleaner code than checking the IP address, but still has the same concern. It's a good thought, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running under IIS the `SERVER_SOFTWARE` property of the `ServerVariables` collection reports something like `Microsoft-IIS/7.5`.

Unfortunately this appears to be blank when running under Cassini.

I don't know if this helps you as it seems the opposite way round to the desired behaviour if you are concerned about security.

**from comments:**

Check the System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName For Cassini it's "WebDev.WebServer40" and for IIS it's "w3wp"

```
string processName= System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName;
if (processName == "WebDev.WebServer40")
{
   // testing
   // Insert code that you want to happen if this is running in Visual Studio
}
```

If this is running in IIS, the pName variable will be “w3wp.  In Visual Studio on a .NET 4.0 app, it’s  “WebDev.WebServer40”.  (I haven’t checked but I assume it would be WebDev.WebServer20 for ASP.NET 2.0)

Comment: Not so much security.  We don't use this on anything with truly sensitive info.  The worst that would happen on these would be a Store leader sees info that is meant for a District Leader.  There's no financials, and no performance/HR stuff.  It's on internal sites where we use a userID passed from another system (similar to OpenId) and we want to bypass it in order to see how the website would look under a particular user.  This is actually perfect.  I'll try it out.

Comment: Darn.  Didn't work.  I assume it's because we have IIS configured to not broadcast this.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: I found it!  Your answer was close enough to lead me down the right path.  I checked the System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName  For Cassini it's "WebDev.WebServer40"  and for IIS it's "w3wp"  Even though your answerer was not the one I was looking for, you led me down the right path, so if you want to modify yours, I'll accept it so the next person trying to figure it out can find it.

Comment: @David If the answer isn't updated, just answer it yourself and mark as correct.  I found this to be a very nice piece of code to have tucked away.

Comment: Yeah, I just hate answering my own questions, especially when others took the time to try.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you use build symbols? Setup your build symbol and then do a #IF PROD then run the authentication. So when you're in debug mode, it'll skip authentication entirely. Hope that helps!